# Browse All Albums using MWPhotoBrowser

Tags: ios, objective-c, mwphotobrowser

I can't forever read and try to understand the whole codes of MWPhotoBrowser's Example Project. I can't figure out where does this project get the Photos data. I've been trying to understand the project since last week.

So here's the thing, I'm trying to make an app that uses this MWPhotoBrowser (https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser/blob/master/README.md) open source project/library. An app that can browse all the albums in my phone but using the MWPhotoBrowser.

In the example proejct of the MWPhotoBrowser, there's a sample code how to browse the local photos of the phone. There are lots of examples but I managed to delete some of them and retain just the last one option. - Library Photos and Videos (Case:9 if you're going to look at the code).

What I have done so far:

1. Implement the open source project (Gallery Viewer App) from developer.apple.com - successfully implemented, but I'm not satisfied because MWPhotoBrowser is better and cooler.
2. Edit the Sample Project of MWPhotoBrowser.

CODE:

```
//
//  Menu.m
//  MWPhotoBrowser
//
//  Created by Michael Waterfall on 21/10/2010.
//  Copyright 2010 d3i. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Photos/Photos.h>
#import "Menu.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "MWCommon.h"

@implementation Menu

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark View

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Test toolbar hiding
    //    [self setToolbarItems: @[[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:nil action:nil]]];
    //    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
    NSLog(@"view did load....");

    self.title = @"MWPhotoBrowser";

    // Clear cache for testing
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearDisk];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];

    [self loadAssets];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    //    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    //    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}

- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationNone;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSInteger rows = 1;
    @synchronized(_assets) {
        if (_assets.count) rows++;
    }
    return rows;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Create
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.accessoryType = _segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 ? UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator : UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    // Configure
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0: {
            cell.textLabel.text = @"Library photos and videos";
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"media from device library";
            break;
        }
        default: break;
    }
    return cell;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view delegate
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Did Select...");

    // Browser
    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *thumbs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MWPhoto *photo, *thumb;
    BOOL displayActionButton = YES;
    BOOL displaySelectionButtons = NO;
    BOOL displayNavArrows = NO;
    BOOL enableGrid = YES;
    BOOL startOnGrid = NO;
    BOOL autoPlayOnAppear = NO;
    //@synchronized(_assets) {
    NSMutableArray *copy = [_assets copy];

    if (NSClassFromString(@"PHAsset")) {
        // Photos library
        UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        CGFloat scale = screen.scale;
        // Sizing is very rough... more thought required in a real implementation
        CGFloat imageSize = MAX(screen.bounds.size.width, screen.bounds.size.height) * 1.5;
        CGSize imageTargetSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize * scale, imageSize * scale);
        CGSize thumbTargetSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize / 3.0 * scale, imageSize / 3.0 * scale);
        for (PHAsset *asset in copy) {
            [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithAsset:asset targetSize:imageTargetSize]];
            [thumbs addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithAsset:asset targetSize:thumbTargetSize]];
        }
    }

    else {
        // Assets library
        for (ALAsset *asset in copy) {
            MWPhoto *photo = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:asset.defaultRepresentation.url];
            [photos addObject:photo];
            MWPhoto *thumb = [MWPhoto photoWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail]];
            [thumbs addObject:thumb];
            if ([asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] == ALAssetTypeVideo) {
                photo.videoURL = asset.defaultRepresentation.url;
                thumb.isVideo = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //}

    self.photos = photos;
    self.thumbs = thumbs;

    // Create browser
    MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    browser.displayActionButton = displayActionButton;
    browser.displayNavArrows = displayNavArrows;
    browser.displaySelectionButtons = displaySelectionButtons;
    browser.alwaysShowControls = displaySelectionButtons;
    browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES;
    browser.enableGrid = enableGrid;
    browser.startOnGrid = startOnGrid;
    browser.enableSwipeToDismiss = NO;
    browser.autoPlayOnAppear = autoPlayOnAppear;
    [browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:0];

    // Test custom selection images
    //    browser.customImageSelectedIconName = @"ImageSelected.png";
    //    browser.customImageSelectedSmallIconName = @"ImageSelectedSmall.png";

    // Reset selections
    if (displaySelectionButtons) {
        _selections = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < photos.count; i++) {
            [_selections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }
    }

    // Show
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];


}

#pragma mark - MWPhotoBrowserDelegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
    return _photos.count;
}

- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < _photos.count)
        return [_photos objectAtIndex:index];
    return nil;
}

- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < _thumbs.count)
        return [_thumbs objectAtIndex:index];
    return nil;
}

//- (MWCaptionView *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser captionViewForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
//    MWPhoto *photo = [self.photos objectAtIndex:index];
//    MWCaptionView *captionView = [[MWCaptionView alloc] initWithPhoto:photo];
//    return [captionView autorelease];
//}

- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser actionButtonPressedForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"ACTION!");
}

- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser didDisplayPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"Did start viewing photo at index %lu", (unsigned long)index);
}

- (BOOL)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser isPhotoSelectedAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [[_selections objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];
}

//- (NSString *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser titleForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
//    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo %lu", (unsigned long)index+1];
//}

- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index selectedChanged:(BOOL)selected {
    [_selections replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:selected]];
    NSLog(@"Photo at index %lu selected %@", (unsigned long)index, selected ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}




//////////////

#pragma mark - Load Assets

- (void)loadAssets {
    if (NSClassFromString(@"PHAsset")) {

        // Check library permissions
        PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
                if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
                    [self performLoadAssets];
                }
            }];
        } else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            [self performLoadAssets];
        }

    } else {

        // Assets library
        [self performLoadAssets];

    }
}

- (void)performLoadAssets {

    // Initialise
    _assets = [NSMutableArray new];

    // Load
    if (NSClassFromString(@"PHAsset")) {

        // Photos library iOS >= 8
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
            options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
            PHFetchResult *fetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
            [fetchResults enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [_assets addObject:obj];
            }];
            if (fetchResults.count > 0) {
//                [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
            }
        });

    } else {

        // Assets Library iOS < 8
        _ALAssetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        // Run in the background as it takes a while to get all assets from the library
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            // Process assets
            void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                if (result != nil) {
                    NSString *assetType = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
                    if ([assetType isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto] || [assetType isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                        [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];
                        NSURL *url = result.defaultRepresentation.url;
                        [_ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:url
                                          resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                              if (asset) {
                                                  @synchronized(_assets) {
                                                      [_assets addObject:asset];
                                                      if (_assets.count == 1) {
                                                          // Added first asset so reload data
                                                          [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                             NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!");
                                         }];

                    }
                }
            };

            // Process groups
            void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) (ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                if (group != nil) {
                    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:assetEnumerator];
                    [assetGroups addObject:group];
                }
            };

            // Process!
            [_ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                                            usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                                          failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"There is an error");
                                          }];

        });

    }

}

@end
```

3. Next, I tried to make a ViewController inside the Storyboard of the sample project, disconnected the connection between the navigation controller and the Table View controller. I Connected the Navigation Controller to ViewController. I then assigned my newly made class named: MainViewController.m to ViewController in the storyboard.
4. I copied all the codes, or rather, copy all the implementation of codes in the Main.m (the class connected to Table View of the sample project), to my MainViewController.m. So here's the code of mine so far:

   ```
   //
   ```

   //  MainViewController.m
   //  MWPhotoBrowser
   //
   //  Created by Glenn on 9/28/15.
   //  Copyright (

c) 2015 Michael Waterfall. All rights reserved.
    //

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import <Photos/Photos.h>
// #import "Menu.h"
#import "SDImageCache.h"
#import "MWCommon.h"

@interface MainViewController ()
{
    MWPhotoBrowser *browser;
}
@end

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [self mwSetup];

    self.title = @"MWPhotoBrowser";

    // Clear cache for testing
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearDisk];
    [[SDImageCache sharedImageCache] clearMemory];

    [self loadAssets];

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    //    self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    //    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    //    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    //    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
    return NO;
}

- (UIStatusBarAnimation)preferredStatusBarUpdateAnimation {
    return UIStatusBarAnimationNone;
}


- (void)mwSetup
{


    NSLog(@"Did Select...");

    // Browser
    NSMutableArray *photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *thumbs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    MWPhoto *photo, *thumb;
    BOOL displayActionButton = YES;
    BOOL displaySelectionButtons = NO;
    BOOL displayNavArrows = NO;
    BOOL enableGrid = YES;
    BOOL startOnGrid = NO;
    BOOL autoPlayOnAppear = NO;
    //@synchronized(_assets) {
    NSMutableArray *copy = [_assets copy];

    if (NSClassFromString(@"PHAsset")) {
        // Photos library
        UIScreen *screen = [UIScreen mainScreen];
        CGFloat scale = screen.scale;
        // Sizing is very rough... more thought required in a real implementation
        CGFloat imageSize = MAX(screen.bounds.size.width, screen.bounds.size.height) * 1.5;
        CGSize imageTargetSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize * scale, imageSize * scale);
        CGSize thumbTargetSize = CGSizeMake(imageSize / 3.0 * scale, imageSize / 3.0 * scale);
        for (PHAsset *asset in copy) {
            [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithAsset:asset targetSize:imageTargetSize]];
            [thumbs addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithAsset:asset targetSize:thumbTargetSize]];
        }
    }

    else {
        // Assets library
        for (ALAsset *asset in copy) {
            MWPhoto *photo = [MWPhoto photoWithURL:asset.defaultRepresentation.url];
            [photos addObject:photo];
            MWPhoto *thumb = [MWPhoto photoWithImage:[UIImage imageWithCGImage:asset.thumbnail]];
            [thumbs addObject:thumb];
            if ([asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType] == ALAssetTypeVideo) {
                photo.videoURL = asset.defaultRepresentation.url;
                thumb.isVideo = true;
            }
        }
    }
    //}

    self.photos = photos;
    self.thumbs = thumbs;

    // Create browser
    browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    browser.displayActionButton = displayActionButton;
    browser.displayNavArrows = displayNavArrows;
    browser.displaySelectionButtons = displaySelectionButtons;
    browser.alwaysShowControls = displaySelectionButtons;
    browser.zoomPhotosToFill = YES;
    browser.enableGrid = enableGrid;
    browser.startOnGrid = startOnGrid;
    browser.enableSwipeToDismiss = NO;
    browser.autoPlayOnAppear = autoPlayOnAppear;
    [browser setCurrentPhotoIndex:0];

    // Test custom selection images
    //    browser.customImageSelectedIconName = @"ImageSelected.png";
    //    browser.customImageSelectedSmallIconName = @"ImageSelectedSmall.png";

    // Reset selections
    if (displaySelectionButtons) {
        _selections = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < photos.count; i++) {
            [_selections addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
        }
    }

    // Show
[self.navigationController pushViewController:browser animated:YES];
    //[self.view addSubview:browser.view];

}





#pragma mark - MWPhotoBrowserDelegate

- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
    return _photos.count;
}

- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < _photos.count)
        return [_photos objectAtIndex:index];
    return nil;
}

- (id <MWPhoto>)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser thumbPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < _thumbs.count)
        return [_thumbs objectAtIndex:index];
    return nil;
}

//- (MWCaptionView *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser captionViewForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
//    MWPhoto *photo = [self.photos objectAtIndex:index];
//    MWCaptionView *captionView = [[MWCaptionView alloc] initWithPhoto:photo];
//    return [captionView autorelease];
//}

- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser actionButtonPressedForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"ACTION!");
}

- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser didDisplayPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    NSLog(@"Did start viewing photo at index %lu", (unsigned long)index);
}

- (BOOL)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser isPhotoSelectedAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [[_selections objectAtIndex:index] boolValue];
}

//- (NSString *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser titleForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
//    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Photo %lu", (unsigned long)index+1];
//}

- (void)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index selectedChanged:(BOOL)selected {
    [_selections replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:selected]];
    NSLog(@"Photo at index %lu selected %@", (unsigned long)index, selected ? @"YES" : @"NO");
}




#pragma mark - Load Assets

- (void)loadAssets {
    if (NSClassFromString(@"PHAsset")) {

        // Check library permissions
        PHAuthorizationStatus status = [PHPhotoLibrary authorizationStatus];
        if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined) {
            [PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status) {
                if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
                    [self performLoadAssets];
                }
            }];
        } else if (status == PHAuthorizationStatusAuthorized) {
            [self performLoadAssets];
        }

    } else {

        // Assets library
        [self performLoadAssets];

    }
}

- (void)performLoadAssets {

    // Initialise
    _assets = [NSMutableArray new];

    // Load
    if (NSClassFromString(@"PHAsset")) {

        // Photos library iOS >= 8
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            PHFetchOptions *options = [PHFetchOptions new];
            options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
            PHFetchResult *fetchResults = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
            [fetchResults enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
                [_assets addObject:obj];
            }];
            if (fetchResults.count > 0) {
                [browser reloadData];  }
        });

    } else {

        // Assets Library iOS < 8
        _ALAssetsLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        // Run in the background as it takes a while to get all assets from the library
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            NSMutableArray *assetGroups = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSMutableArray *assetURLDictionaries = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

            // Process assets
            void (^assetEnumerator)(ALAsset *, NSUInteger, BOOL *) = ^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                if (result != nil) {
                    NSString *assetType = [result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
                    if ([assetType isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto] || [assetType isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo]) {
                        [assetURLDictionaries addObject:[result valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyURLs]];
                        NSURL *url = result.defaultRepresentation.url;
                        [_ALAssetsLibrary assetForURL:url
                                          resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {
                                              if (asset) {
                                                  @synchronized(_assets) {
                                                      [_assets addObject:asset];
                                                      if (_assets.count == 1) {
                                                          // Added first asset so reload data
                                                          [browser reloadData];
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                         failureBlock:^(NSError *error){
                                             NSLog(@"operation was not successfull!");
                                         }];

                    }
                }
            };

            // Process groups
            void (^ assetGroupEnumerator) (ALAssetsGroup *, BOOL *) = ^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
                if (group != nil) {
                    [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:assetEnumerator];
                    [assetGroups addObject:group];
                }
            };

            // Process!
            [_ALAssetsLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll
                                            usingBlock:assetGroupEnumerator
                                          failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                              NSLog(@"There is an error");
                                          }];

        });

    }

}

@end
```

Please help. And can someone help me edit the format of my 2nd code? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Okay, so I got it working. Basically, the MWPhotoBrowser needs a first view controller before loading itself.

For instance, in the sample project, the first screen is the Table View. Then you will select between the 9 rows, after that, the MWPhotoBrowser viewcontroller will be showed.

In my implementation, I just made a first view controller, and then added a button. When you click the button, the MWPhotoBrowser will be showed.

So that's how MWPhotoBrowser works. It doesn't load the photos and videos if you push the MWPhotoBrowser inside the ViewWillAppear, ViewDidLoad, ViewDidAppear.

Now, I have to learn or know how to load videos and photos from different album.